# Dynamic pattern for validateRegex is not working, but Static version is

Tags: regex, jsf

I have JSF page. My aim is to build validator dynamically by getting pattern from database.

My code below not working.  I mean regex fails.

```
<p:inputText value="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenID}" 
             requiredMessage="Lütfen Tavsiye Edilen ID giriniz"
             validatorMessage="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDHataMesaji}"
             rendered="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDRendered}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDRegEX}" />
</p:inputText>
```

but this working as expected

```
<p:inputText value="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenID}" 
             requiredMessage="Lütfen Tavsiye Edilen ID giriniz"
             validatorMessage="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDHataMesaji}"
             rendered="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDRendered}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="\d" />
</p:inputText>
```

`basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDRegEX` equals to `\d`. I checked it by printing it on the JSF page.

What must I do in order to make it work?

Backing bean's related part

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BasvuruBean implements Serializable {

private Basvuru basvuru = new Basvuru();
private Sistem sistem;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String url;
private List<Sistem> sistemler = new ArrayList<Sistem>();
private SistemDAO sistemDAO = new SistemDAO();

    @PostConstruct
void initialiseSession() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    sistem=sistemler.get(0);
}

public BasvuruBean() {

    sistemler = sistemDAO.tumSistemler();


    this.basvuru.setSistem(sistem);
    this.basvuru.setSirketAdi("Şirket Adı");
    this.basvuru.setePosta("posta@sirket.com");

}


public void sistemChangeListener() {

    System.out.println(sistem.getSistemAdi());
    sistem.setKapsamaYaricapi(this.sistem.getKapsamaYaricapiDefault());
    this.sistem.setKapsamaYuksekligi(this.sistem.getKapsamaYuksekligiDefault());
    this.sistem.setFrekansMax(this.sistem.getFrekansMaxDefault());
    this.sistem.setFrekansMin(this.sistem.getFrekansMinDefault());
    this.sistem.setTavsiyeEdilenID(this.sistem.getTavsiyeEdilenIDDefault());
    this.sistem.setRunway(this.sistem.getRunwayDefault());
    this.sistem.setTrueRadiationDirection(this.sistem.getTrueRadiationDirectionDefault());
    this.sistem.setApproachCAT(this.sistem.getApproachCATDefault());
    this.sistem.setAntenVericiGucuDefault(this.sistem.getAntenVericiGucuDefault());
    this.sistem.setAntenYuksekligiAGL(this.sistem.getAntenYuksekligiAGLDefault());
    this.sistem.setFrekans(this.sistem.getFrekansDefault());
}
}
```

and selectonemenu which changes sistem object

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem}" converter="sistemConverter">
  <f:selectItems value="#{basvuruBean.sistemler}" var="s" itemLabel="#{s.sistemAdi}" itemValue="#{s}" />
  <p:ajax listener="#{basvuruBean.sistemChangeListener}" update="p2 genelbilgi" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Can you show us your backing bean? At least all relevant parts of it.

Comment: I have added some more code portions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to naildown the cause in your code as it is relatively clumsy.

Fact is, the `<f:validateRegex>` is a view build time tag. So, referencing a view scoped bean property in it would cause a completely new instance to be created which is different from the instance as referenced in UI components like `<p:selectOneMenu>`. So, effectively, you end up with 2 backing bean instances, one referenced by `<f:validateRegex>` and another one referenced by `<p:selectOneMenu>` and its `<p:ajax>`. So, if you manipulate the regex pattern by ajax in one bean instance, it wouldn't get reflected in the other bean instance.

The possible design problem aside, you can solve the particular functional problem by using the [`<o:validator>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) from [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) instead of `<f:validateRegex>`.

```
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="#{basvuruBean.basvuru.sistem.tavsiyeEdilenIDRegEX}" />
```

This will resolve the attributes during rendertime instead of buildtime.